# Like Box Social Plugin iframe doesn't scroll in an UIWebView

Tags: ios, facebook, uiwebview, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

I loaded the [Like Box `iframe` code generated on Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) into an `UIWebView` on my iPhone App. It works well, but when I scroll, it scrolls the `UIWebView` itself, and not the content inside the `iframe`. How can I block the `UIWebView` from scrolling (i.e the `UIWebView` takes the fullscreen frame) and allow the overflowed content of the `iframe` to scroll instead ?

ps : I tested a simple .html in MobileSafari.app and I have the same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use two fingers in the like box instead of one. Then it scrolls.

Comment: I found out it works like this indeed. And on iOS 5 it works with one finger. If anyone have a solution (catching `touchMoved` ?) I'm open though

Answer (score 0):

You won't have much control over a plugin that is rendered as an iframe due to cross domain restrictions and they do not give many options to customize the appearance.

You could replace it with a [Facebook like button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).  Then below it, you could add code that reads and displays the Fan Page feed using the [graph api's page's feed](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) connection (/pageId/feed). This would give you full control over the rendering and still gives the user the option to like your page.  To improve performance of this solution you could use the [Facebook real-time updates API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) to get notified when new updates get posted to the page and then you could pull those down and cache them.